# Does anyone use command line exclusively for managing mysql DB?

Tags: mysql, command-line

I find it quite not user friendly, but I wonder if I'm doing something wrong... maybe there are some flags I'm not aware of that can help me display data in a better more screen friendly way?

[image]

Comment: Really no reason to use it in my opinion. There is Workbench and even if your server is locked on that port, you can tunnel traffic through SSH.

Comment: @Trent yes I use sequelpro right now to tunnel through SSH. But command line is sexier. Just need to find a better way to display data.

Comment: people use it in colleges when learning.....

Comment: Nothing sexier about it really - I find command-line is just elitist crap that makes people feel superior about their abilities. If there is an easy way to do things, it's the best way. If you can run raw SQL in the utility (which you can); I'm not sure there is any benefit of using the command line

Comment: that being said - I'm not really a DBA; so maybe the command-line provides some functionality that I've never really had to use?

Comment: The reason why you should know how to use the command line tool is that the cli can use every feature (whereas your tool might or might not have such or such feature), it is available everywhere (so getting on a new project you are sure that you will be able to quickly get to it rather than have to ask for another tool to be installed on top of it before you can work), and ultimately it is not difficult to use at all, since it's mostly a matter of habit. I tend to use heidisql myself as an external tool most of the time, but knowing the native cli tool first is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use \G at the end of your query to display table columns as rows and make it easier to see the result set

```
mysql> select * from users;
+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id_user | name    | email                 | salt             | hash                                     | created_at          |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|     ... | ...     | ...                   | ...              | ...                                      | ...                 |
...
X row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from users\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   id_user: ...
      name: ...
     email: ...
      salt: ...
      hash: ...
created_at: ...
X row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I always prefer the \G flag, however on ms command line, it the result set is large, it sometimes hides the first results found. But +1 for the \G flag

Comment: @PhilCross: sadly that's mostly due to windows' command prompt and interpreter being horribly outdated pieces of software. If you're looking for an alternative you can have a look at [MSYS Bash for windows](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), or try your luck with [Microsoft's PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :) Fortunately I only need to use command line in emergencies! (I do love phpMyAdmin!)